# Write in a Json file with Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js

I have a little nodejs script

```
var slug = require('slug');
var fs = require('fs');
var file = '../_data.json';
var config;
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
 if (err) {
 console.log('Error: ' + err);
 return;
}
config = JSON.parse(data);


 var slugTitle = slug('title').toLowerCase().split('.').join("");
 var newPost = {"description": 'mydescription', "title": 'mytitle'};

    config[slugTitle] = newPost;

    fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(config, null,  2), function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } 
      }
    }); 
    rl.close();
  });     
  });
 });
 });
```

The script work fine, but the new item go in the bottom of my json file. Are there any simple way to write the new enter on the top of the json and to not change the order of the other items.

My json is something like that :

```
{
  "index": {
       "title":"Blague Sexy",
       "description": "description to to "
  },
  "page1": {
      "title":"page1",
      "description" : 'description lo lo' 
  }
}
```

I'm using another code build on harpjs wich read the json by starting from the top to down. I'm trying to not modify this code.

In advance thanks.

Comment: sorry. Bad copy paste. I correct it.

Comment: any chance of getting jsfiddle of this? I have some suggestions.

Comment: again.. what is new enter

Comment: lol ! It' the new item in my json file. Like 'page2'

Comment: @mcbjam A JSON map is unordered.  Is there a reason you care about the order?  Whatever you're doing is likely to break.

Comment: so what you want.. not go it on the bottom, and go to the top.. well does it really matter in case of json properties?

Comment: if there is an array you might consider ordering, why would you ever want to order properties inside Object

Comment: I'm using Harpjs for construct the website. Here is an exemple : http://www.mcbjam.com/. Harpjs read the file in it's order. If i add a file on the bottom, it will be my first post

Comment: Are you by change following [this recipe](http://harpjs.com/recipes/blog-posts-list)?

Comment: @JasperWoudenberg Hi. Yes it's how i display the post list.

Comment: You could add the objects into an array, then add an index to the json collection, then sort the array by the index which you have provided for each collection.